# A regular expression to match/split on elements of a java bytecode method signature?

Tags: java, regex

This might be beyond the utility of regular expressions, but...

A method signature in java bytecode starts with `(`, is followed by a list of either

- for each primitive argument: single letter primitive type code (I = int, Z = boolean and so on)
- for each object argument: L and then the package path plus a semicolon  e.g. `Lcom/packagename/Someclass;`
- for each array argument:  `[` then either a primitive code or an object argument
- also note arrays of arrays are indicated with `[[` and then the type code.  nested arrays can go on for a while.  e.g.  `[[[[I` for int[][][][]
- finally a closing `)` and a type code for the return type.

so the code for `public String replace(char c1, char c2, String s) {}` is `(CC)Ljava/lang/String;`

the code for `public int[][][][][][][][][][] ouch() {}` is `()[[[[[[[[[[I`

I've started with this java regular expression, which seems to capture some things, but doesn't always work.   Also, I have no idea how to capture the Lobject; types.

```
\([B-Z]{0,1}|[\[]+[B-Z]{0,1}\)([A-Z]|[\[]+[A-Z])
```

I'm using [this](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) excellent online java regexp tester.

update:  I'm going to simplify this a bit and consider only the items inside the parens and not consider the object class yet.

I've come up with this

```
\((\[*I|\[*S|\[*C|\[*B|\[*F|\[*D|\[*Z)*\)
```

that does match things like  `(ISCBFDZ)`, `(I)`, `(I[[C)` and `(I[C)`.  But it seems to be grouping ISCBFDZ as one single string, which I don't understand.

Comment: I don't know of all the formatting particulars. As long as its not recursive, you shouldn't have a problem. Also, you can save yourself some grief by not using a class to represent a single character (unless a space,tab for readability). So, `\([B-Z]{0,1}|\[+[B-Z]{0,1}\)([A-Z]|\[+[A-Z])` is a little more readable.

Comment: why aren't you using [http://asm.ow2.org/] ASM to parse java byte code?

Comment: @dkatzel I actually, am, but I didn't think they had a utility to do this.  I dug a big deeper and found org.objectweb.asm.Type.getArgumentTypes(...).  I think this will serve my purposes.    But I'm still curious as to how to do this with a regex.

Comment: `But it seems to be grouping ISCBFDZ as one single string, which I don't understand.` If you factor out the optional `\[*` in each of the alternations, it is essentially this `\((?:\[*[ISCBFDZ]+)*\)` That's the reason the overall match would be `(SCBFDZ)`. If you _require_ a `[` between each letter, that's something different.

Comment: Unless the regex engine supports recursive expressions (Java does not support it), regex is not the right tool to match/understand nested content - it just can't realistically do it. You need a *parser*, which can keep track of the depth of nesting. However, if you edit your question to include some examples of input that matches with the desired captured groups, and other examples of input that does not match, someone might be able to get something working.